# Am I really sleeping if I wake up with lingering memory of my dream many times into the night?

Tags: sleep

I suffer insomnia sometimes. When that happens, I would lie on my bed and find that my mind is active. As hours go on, I would seem like falling into dreams, only to wake up later. The process of falling into dreams and wake up with a lingering memory of the dream would repeat many times into the night.

When the next day comes, I would find that I am tired and my mind is not as sharp as the normal days.

So I wonder when that happens, do I really have enough rest for the night? Am I really sleeping?

Answer (score 1):

Superficially, yes, that sounds like fairly poor sleep. Don't loose hope entirely, though - in general, when people say "I never fell asleep all night" or "I kept waking up in the middle of the night", but are observed while sleeping, many still do have periods of uninterrupted sleep that they don't remember.

So, nights like you describe sound like you are getting poor sleep, but chances are you're getting *some* sleep.

Still, it sounds rough! I'm sorry this is an issue you deal with.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It is nice of you to be sympathetic and try to help the OP, but answers at Health have to be backed up with reliable references. References are helping the community assess the merit of an answer regardless of the readers' background. You can always [edit] your answer to add some. For more information on site policies, please take our [tour] and visit the [help] and [meta]. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the welcome! I do not recall the journal where I read that, but I wanted to post the answer regardless.